# Powershell: Получить IPv4 адрес и использовать его в качестве аргумента для команды netsh

Tags: powershell, netsh, ipv6

Приветствую!

Начну издалека. Недавно захотел настроить себе подключение по IPv6 через tunnelbroker, но вот незадача - мой интернет провайдер выдаёт белые динамические IPv4 адреса, поэтому нужно автоматизировать процесс обновления адреса туннеля. Сам tunnelbroker предлагает решение, но оно работает только на его стороне, а на моей нет, поэтому каждый раз при смене IPv4 адреса приходится удалять старый туннель и создавать новый. 
Усердно погуглив, нашёл решение, но у меня возникли проблемы с получением IPv4 адреса и передаче его в качестве аргумента для функции netsh. Связался с автором кода, но тот пару раз ответил и затих, а проблема так и не осталась решённой. 
Вот, собственно, ссылка на первоисточник: 
http://josherickson.org/132/hurricane-electric-6in4-windows-startup-script/

```
function fastpingtest {
    $ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping;
    $ping.Send("8.8.8.8", 1000).status -eq "success";
}
$endtime = [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(1);
$mapipv6 = $false; 
while([datetime]::Now -lt $endtime) {
    if(fastpingtest) { $mapipv6 = $true; break; }
}

if($mapipv6) {
    $wc = New-Object net.webclient;
    $url= "https://ipv4.tunnelbroker.net/ipv4_end.php?ip=AUTO&pass={1}&apikey={0}&tid={2}";

    $values = "USERID", "PASSWORDMD5HASH", TUNNELID;
    $wc.DownloadString(($url -f $values));

    #get connected interface
    $interface = netsh interface ipv4 show interface | findstr /c:" connected" | ?{!$_.contains("Loopback");} | %{[regex]::Split($_, "( )+") | ?{$_.trim().length -gt 0} | %{$_.trim()}; }
    $interface_ip = (netsh interface ipv4 show address $interface[0] | findstr /c:"IP Address" | select -First 1).split(":")[1].trim()
    netsh interface teredo set state disabled
    netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel $interface_ip HEIPv4ENDPOINT
    netsh interface ipv6 add address IP6Tunnel YOURIPv6ADDRESS
    netsh interface ipv6 add route ::/0 IP6Tunnel HEIPv6ADDRESS
```

Проблемы начинаются после комментария **#get connected interface** 
Автор посоветовал поменять **!$*.contains("Loopback");*** на **$.contains("Satel");** (потому что моё подключение к интернету так называется), также я посчитал логичным поменять **findstr /c:"IP Address"** на **findstr /c:"IP-Адрес"**, так как оригинальный код писался под англоязычную систему, а у меня - русский язык. 
Но всё равно проблема та же - в переменную **$interface_ip** записывается некорректный адрес (или не записывается вообще), соответственно команде netsh передаются неправильные параметры, и ничего не работает.

Прогуглив тему извлечения IPv4 адреса, нашёл другой вариант.

```
   #get connected interface
    $ipAddress = Test-Connection -ComputerName EAGauss -Count 1  | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
    $interface_ip = $ipAddress.IPAddressToString
```

Где EAGauss - имя хоста (моего компьютера), я было обрадовался, потому что выполняя эти пару команд, всё работает и выводится мой IPv4 адрес, но когда я заменяю старый кусок кода, на этот, всё равно получаю ошибку:

**-ERROR: Invalid IPv4 address supplied**

Что значит что функции netsh передан неверный параметр.

Прошу помощи. 
С Уважением, 
EAGauss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

наконец, решил проблему - поделюсь решением.
Ошибку -ERROR: Invalid IPv4 address supplied выдавал не netsh, а сайт tunnelbroker при авторизации.
Решил как:
Перечитал Tunnelbroker.net API https://forums.he.net/index.php?topic=3153.0
И подправил:

```
function fastpingtest  
    { 
    $ping = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping; 
    $ping.Send("8.8.8.8", 1000).status -eq "success"; } 
    $endtime = [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(1); 
    $mapipv6 = $false;  
while([datetime]::Now -lt $endtime)  
    {  
if(fastpingtest)  
    {  
    $mapipv6 = $true; break;  
    }  
    } 
if($mapipv6)  
    { $ipAddress = Test-Connection -ComputerName hostname -Count 1  | Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address 
    $interface_ip = $ipAddress.IPAddressToString  
    $wc = New-Object net.webclient; 
    $url= "https://ipv4.tunnelbroker.net/ipv4_end.php?ip={0}&pass={1}&user_id={2}&tid={3}"; 
    $values = $interface_ip, "MD5PASS", "USERID", TUNNELID; 
    $wc.DownloadString(($url -f $values)); 
    netsh interface ipv6 add address IP6Tunnel ClientIPv6Address 
    netsh interface ipv6 add route ::/0 IP6Tunnel ServerIPv6Address 
    netsh interface ipv6 delete interface IP6Tunnel 
    netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel $interface_ip ServerIPv4Address 
    }
```

Где hostname - имя локального хоста; 
MD5PASS - Update Key (Личный кабинет tunnelbroker, страница туннеля, вкладка Advanced) 
USERID - User ID (Личный кабинет tunnelbroker) 
TUNNELID - Tunnel ID (Личный кабинет tunnelbroker, страница туннеля)
ClientIPv6Address, ServerIPv6Address, ServerIPv4Address - соответственно (Личный кабинет tunnelbroker, страница туннеля).

Теперь выдаёт ошибку: -ERROR: This tunnel is already associated with this IP address. Please try to limit your updates to IP changes. 
Но это нормально, потому что мой IPv4 адрес ещё не успел поменяться и ещё не прошло 5 минут после предыдущего запроса.

Answer (score 0):

> Прогуглив тему извлечения IPv4 адреса, нашёл другой вариант.

```powershell
$ipAddress = Test-Connection -ComputerName EAGauss -Count 1  |
    Select -ExpandProperty IPV4Address
$interface_ip = $ipAddress.IPAddressToString
```

Имя компьютера можно брать из окружения, пример:

```powershell
$interface_ip = (Test-Connection -ComputerName ([System.Environment]::MachineName) -Count 1).IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
```

> ...когда я заменяю старый кусок кода, на этот, всё равно получаю ошибку:
>
> -ERROR: Invalid IPv4 address supplied
>
> Что значит что функции netsh передан неверный параметр

Я бы сначала проверил, работает ли вызов `netsh` из PowerShell с хардкоженными параметрами. Возможно, где-то неправильно передаются аргументы, у PowerShell вызовы сторонних исполняемых файлов иногда требуют [особой магии](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/).

Пример, все IPv4\IPv6 адреса выдуманы, замените на свои:

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel IP6Tunnel 1.2.3.4 4.3.2.1
netsh interface ipv6 add address IP6Tunnel 2001:0db8:0a0b:12f0:0000:0000:0000:0001
netsh interface ipv6 add route ::/0 IP6Tunnel 2001:0db8:0a0b:12f0:0000:0000:0000:0001
```